# javascript: changing order of values for all keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

I have an object with the following structure:

```
object = { ids: [], labels:[], values:[] }
```

each key has 80 values. I want to sort the 'values' key in descending order (biggest to smallest), and update the ids and labels keys accordingly (so the label and id of the highest 'values' value is now first). I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
function getSorted(arr, sortArr) {
  var result = [];
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(sortArr[i], arr[i]);
    result[i] = arr[sortArr[i]];
  }
  return result;
}
```

the data I am trying to sort is this:

```
ids = [41, 121, 159, 165, 170, 189, 258, 259, 307, 340, 342, 352, 357, 412, 482, 513, 725, 830, 833, 874, 907, 944, 1167, 1169, 1189, 1193, 1208, 1232, 1274, 1314, 1497, 1498, 1503, 1505, 1795, 1950, 1959, 1960, 1962, 1968, 1977, 2011, 2024, 2039, 2065, 2077, 2110, 2167, 2178, 2184, 2186, 2188, 2191, 2235, 2244, 2247, 2264, 2275, 2291, 2318, 2335, 2342, 2350, 2396, 2419, 2475, 2483, 2491, 2546, 2571, 2722, 2737, 2739, 2782, 2811, 2859, 2908, 2936, 2964, 3450]

values = [71, 2, 2, 12, 2, 47, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 50, 2, 2, 113, 2, 2, 10, 3, 36, 3, 19, 163, 2, 51, 6, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 25, 30, 2, 3, 2, 40, 11, 13, 5, 2, 23, 2, 5, 7, 19, 3, 2, 28, 2, 14, 11, 78, 22, 2, 40, 3, 2, 2, 11, 13, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 4, 4, 12, 13, 126, 7, 3, 10, 37]

labels = ["Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria", "Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinomycetales", "Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinomycetales", "Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinomycetales;Actinomycetaceae", "Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinomycetales;Actinomycetaceae;Varibaculum", "Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinomycetales;Corynebacteriaceae", "Bacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinobacteria;Actinomycetales;Corynebacteriaceae;Corynebacterium", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Porphyromonadaceae;Porphyromonas", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Porphyromonadaceae;Porphyromonas", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Porphyromonadaceae;Porphyromonas", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Porphyromonadaceae;Porphyromonas", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Porphyromonadaceae;Porphyromonas", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Porphyromonadaceae;Porphyromonas", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Prevotellaceae", "Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Prevotellaceae;Prevotella", "Bacteria;Firmicutes", "Bacteria;Firmicutes", "Bacteria;Firmicutes", "Bacteria;Firmicutes", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Bacilli;Bacillales;Staphylococcaceae;Staphylococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Anaerococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Finegoldia", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Gallicola", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Gallicola", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Peptoniphilus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Peptoniphilus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;IncertaeSedisXI;Peptoniphilus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;Peptococcaceae;Peptococcus", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;Ruminococcaceae", "Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;Veillonellaceae", "Bacteria;Proteobacteria;Epsilonproteobacteria;Campylobacterales;Campylobacteraceae;Campylobacter"]
```

How should I tackle this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only relationship you have between the three sets of data is the index inside of each array, which will be lost when you sort. To keep the three sets of data paired, I would map over your data and create an object for each:

```
const data = { ids, labels, values };

const list = data.values.map((value, idx) => {
  return {
    id: data.ids[idx],
    value,
    label: data.labels[idx]
  };
});
```

Now `list` contains an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    id: 41,
    label: 'Bacteria',
    value: '71',
  },
  {
    // ... etc
  }
]
```

This is a much easier data structure to work with because you want `id`, `label`, and `value` to remain paired together.

At that point, you can easily sort this array of objects *by the value property descending* like so:

```
list.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.value - a.value;
});
```

And now `list` is an array of objects of your data, sorted by `object.value` descending.

You can use this array of objects, or translate it back into your original format of three different arrays easily.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little different from what you asked, but maybe you can have an idea on how to adapt for your needs.

While ago I made this function to solve a sorting problems on my objects.

```
function sortObj(obj, index, sorting) {
  let ans = [];
  sorting = sorting.toUpperCase();

  if (obj.constructor === Array) {
    for (let i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      ans.push(obj[i]);
    }
  }
  else {
    for (let k in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        ans.push(obj[k])
      }
    }
  }

  if (!ans.length)
    return [];


  if (isNaN(ans[0][index])) {
    ans = ans.sort(function (a,b) {
      if (a[index]) {
        if (sorting === "ASC")
          return a[index].localeCompare(b[index]);
        else
          return b[index].localeCompare(a[index]);
      }
      return [];
    });
  }
  else {
    ans = ans.sort(function (a, b) {
      if (sorting === "ASC")
        return a[index] - b[index];

      else
        return b[index] - a[index];
    })
  }

  return ans;
}

// structure of object
obj = {"1": {id: "1", label: "A", value: "5"}, "2": {id: "2", label: "B", value: "1"}}


sorted = sortObj(obj, "label", "ASC");
// [{id: "1", label: "A", value: "5"}, {id: "2", label: "B", value: "1"}]


sorted = sortObj(obj, "value", "ASC");
// [{id: "2", label: "B", value: "1"}, {id: "1", label: "A", value: "5"}]
```